# How can I calculate the Characteristic Energy to Sun-Earth L1?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, lagrangian-points, falcon-9, earth-observation, noaa

Alternatively, does anyone know it?

I'm asking in regards to the upcoming [DSCOVR](http://forum.nasaspaceflight.com/index.php?topic=30543.0) (Deep Space Climate Observatory) mission scheduled to launch aboard a Falcon 9 v1.1 rocket in January 2015. DSCOVR is 507 kg in mass and will be headed to the Sun-Earth L<sub>1</sub> (SEL1).

I'm trying to calculate the payload fraction of the rocket based off the C<sub>3</sub> (characteristic energy) involved. I'm assuming it'll be greater than 0 km<sup>2</sup>/s<sup>2</sup> and less than 12.2 km<sup>2</sup>/s<sup>2</sup>, which is the C<sub>3</sub> of MAVEN to Mars.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, it's less than zero.  The Lagrange points are still effectively captured by the Earth, so you have not escaped.  [This paper](http://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/20020081116.pdf) states the required $C_3$ as $-0.7\,\mathrm{km^2/s^2}$.

If we ignore the Sun, the $C_3$ required to get to the altitude of the S-E L1 point is:

$$C_3=-{2\mu\over{r_a+r_p}}$$

where $\mu$ is the $G M$ of the Earth and the Moon, and $r_a$ and $r_p$ are the apoapsis (L1) and periapsis (LEO).  The result is $C_3=-0.54\,\mathrm{km^2/s^2}$.  However the Sun is there and helps, hence the $C_3$ of $-0.7\,\mathrm{km^2/s^2}$.