# How can we track where DSCOVR is now?

Tags: trajectory, tracking, dscovr

[Celestia](http://www.shatters.net/celestia/) supports importing spacecraft data, but I didn't see any data for [DSCOVR](http://www.nesdis.noaa.gov/DSCOVR/). Is there any way to see where it is now so we can track it on it's way to Sun-Earth L1?

Comment: Tracking data can take a bit of time depending on the location of the tracking radar. I would expect something within a few days if not hours.

Comment: I couldn't even really find a planned trajectory for it anywhere, has anyone seen one?  I'm assuming it's pretty much a direct flight, and no slingshots around the earth or moon, but I don't really know.

Comment: I have not seen one either. All I know is that it is long ~110 days

Comment: http://www.spaceflight101.com/dscovr.html This is about the bes.

Comment: I think the US Air Force requires that no attitude/orbit data be _real time data_ for security reasons, but I am not sure about this...  However, I doubt that an object near $L_{1}$ is in much danger of attack...

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you take a look at my answer here:
https://space.stackexchange.com/a/23743/21677

I made an app that interpolates EPIC images on a 3D globe, and also displays DSCOVR and its path at any time in the past 2 years since DSCOVR started its service. It's a web app, or a mobile app (Android+iOS) if you open this link from your phone or ablet. It's free and ad-free:

http://app.blueturn.earth

Best,
Michael